# Arduino (C? Based) Programming for Energy Efficiency

Tags: c, performance, arduino, processing-efficiency

I have a question I haven't really been able to find an answer to this specific question.

I recently started a project to setup an Arduino Board to control various LED's to transition through the spectrum from Red to Yellow, Yellow to Green,
Green to Teal, Teal to Blue, Blue to Magenta, Magenta to Red.
Uses Pointers to Map Each RGB Value for full spectrum, based
off 255 indexed array.

My question is in regards to writing code that is energy efficient. I need it to be as efficient as possible because my project will be running off 4 rechargeable AA batteries (1.5V AA each).

How can I write energy efficient code? Or is this a question of futility?

I am running off the assumption (could be very inaccurate) that after the setup is completed there will be less energy consumed during the loop process.

The code in question is below:

```
int const RED = 3 /* Pin 3 */, BLUE = 5 /* Pin 5 */, GREEN = 6 /* Pin 6 */;
int* _RED[1536];
int* _GREEN[1536];
int* _BLUE[1536];
int RGB[256];


void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i<256;++i){
        RGB[i] = i;
    }
//RED TO YELLOW
    for (int i = 0 ; i<256;++i){
        _RED[i] = &RGB[255];
        _GREEN[i] = &RGB[i];
        _BLUE[i] = &RGB[0];
    }
 //YELLOW TO GREEN
    for (int i = 256;i < 512; ++i){
        _RED[i] = &RGB[511-i];
        _GREEN[i] = &RGB[255];
        _BLUE[i] = &RGB[0];
    }
 //GREEN TO TEAL
    for (int i = 512; i <768;++i){
        _RED[i] = &RGB[0];
        _GREEN[i] = &RGB[255];
        _BLUE[i] = &RGB[255+(i-767)];
    }
 //TEAL TO BLUE
    for (int i = 768; i < 1024; ++i){
        _RED[i] = &RGB[0];
        _GREEN[i] = &RGB[1023-i];
        _BLUE[i] = &RGB[255];
    }
 //BLUE TO MAGENTA
    for (int i = 1024; i < 1280; ++i){
        _RED[i] = &RGB[(255+(i-1279))];
        _GREEN[i] = &RGB[0];
        _BLUE[i] = &RGB[255];
    }
 //MAGENTA TO RED
    for (int i = 1280; i < 1536; ++i){
        _RED[i] = &RGB[255];
        _GREEN[i] = &RGB[0];
        _BLUE[i] = &RGB[1535-i];
    }
 //COMPLETES FULL SPECTRUM EXCLUDING WHITE AND BLACK
}

void loop(){
for(int i = 0; i <1536; ++i){
    analogWrite(RED,*_RED[i]);
    analogWrite(GREEN,*_GREEN[i]);
    analogWrite(BLUE,*_BLUE[i]);
    delay(100);
}

}
```

or would it be better to use the code as follows:

```
int const Red = 3,  /* Pin 3 */ Blue = 5, /* Pin 5 */ Green = 6; /* Pin 6 */
void RGB(int R, int G, int B) {
analogWrite(Red,R); analogWrite(Green,G); analogWrite(Blue,B); delay(25);}
void setup() {}
void loop() {
int r=0,g=0,b=0;
r = 255;g = 0;b = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){RGB(r,i,b);}
r = 255; g = 255;b = 0; for (int i = 255; i >= 0; --i){RGB(i,g,b); } 
r = 0;g = 255;b = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){RGB(r,g,i);}
r = 0;g = 255;b = 255; for (int i = 255; i >= 0; --i){RGB(r,i,b);}
r = 0;g = 0;b = 255; for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){RGB(i,g,b);}
r = 255;g = 0;b = 255; for (int i = 255; i >= 0; --i){RGB(r,g,i);}
delay(1000);
     }
```

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: Definitely not the first one, you have an array of pointers which costs you an extra indirection (wasted CPU cycles = wasted power), and the data you're trying to store is smaller than a pointer anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it depends entirely on details of your board. E.g. here's some interesting info on Arduino Zero power management: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoZeroPowerConsumption

Comment: Thanks @Gene all the information I can get will help. Ben I was under the assumption that using a pointer and 1 integer instead of 3 integers would be less space

Comment: Is LED power consumption part of the "energy efficiency"?

Comment: @BrettReinhard: But you have 1536*3 pointers and 256 integers instead of 1536*3 integers, and the value is 0-255 which fits in only 8 bits -- 3 of them are definitely smaller than a pointer plus integer (microcontrollers with 8 bit pointers do exist, but you'd have run out of memory during compilation long ago).  Bigger problem is the doubled pointer dereference as I mentioned, that costs cycles.

Comment: @wallyk it this instance I would not include it as energy consumption as it is essential for the program.

Comment: @wallyk unless there is another "cheaper" way of transitioning colors. Without needing to buy different LEDs. I would be open to using resistors if that would even make a difference, but I believe that would lead us too far off the subject of this forum.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of duty cycle of LEDs being on.

Comment: @wallyk could you further explain this? I've heard duty cycle but don't recall exactly what it is or how it would tie in.

Comment: @Brett: "Pulse Wave Modulation"... easy linear control over LED power, taking advantage of "persistence of vision" in the human visual cortex.  (It does NOT avoid non-linearities in vision, only those in the LED).  Don't try it with computer vision (phototransistors / photodiodes) because they don't experience persistence of vision.

Comment: To amplify Ben's explanation, an LED can be turned on for 1 millisecond (say) and off for 99 milliseconds so that it is "blinked" 100 times per second, and (depending on power level) it might appear (to a human) to be on like a normal indicator, but at a substantial power savings over turning it fully on and not off at all.

Comment: @wallyk thank you for the further explanation. I understand the concept but I think I may be not understanding how this could be implemented within the second code shows in the OP. If I am understanding it correctly I could encapsulate the analog writes in a for loop and adding another write for each pin to say 0 with a delay in between to manually create this pwm? Or am I completely off base here?

Comment: Maybe look at [using sleep modes in Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode). Using `IDLE` mode will reduce the current consumption by about 2/3 while it doesn't interfere with Arduino routines and interrupts.

Comment: @JimmyB so when using

    IDLE the changing of PWM would still occur?

Comment: Yes, in `IDLE`, all interrupts are still active and any of them will wake up the device. That's because only the core CPU clock is disabled during `IDLE`, which is also the reason for the relatively big current consumption in this mode. Deeper sleep modes can reduce consumption by 99% or more, but most subsystems (and interrupts) are then disabled and cannot be used for wake up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these programs will have roughly equal (and rather high) energy usage, as the Arduino `delay()` function does not put the processor into a sleep state. If power consumption is important, you will need to put the processor into sleep mode yourself. Unfortunately, the Arduino framework does not expose any way to do this; you will need to drop down to the appropriate AVR registers and intrinsics to do this.

Another problem will be that the first program requires about 10 KB of RAM for your four arrays, which is significantly more than is available on most AVR microcontrollers. Generally speaking, large lookup tables should be avoided on this platform.

Comment: I don't know how inefficient the `analogWrite` function is, maybe it does indeed make both equal.  But the number of operations in OP's code in the operating loop (not even counting setup) is much much higher in the first version.

Comment: This code would be run on an arduino 101 or zero, which both have a ram of 28-32KB. That being said , I'm starting to think that the code has less of an impact compared to which board is being used.

Comment: @BenVoigt The number of operations is irrelevant here. The processor is in RUN mode 100% of the time, as `delay()` is a spinloop.

Comment: @duskwuff: Yeah... spinloop may not have the same power characteristics as typical application code, but even if it saves a little (because e.g. SIMD and FPU transistors aren't switching, of course these Atmel processors don't have any) it's at best a few tens of percent power saving, not the 98% you'd get from a sleep mode.  And on some processors a tight loop may well be higher than average consumption.

Comment: @BrettReinhard It'd actually be closer to 20 KB on those boards, incidentally. `int` and pointers are 16 bits on AVR, and 32 bits on ARM. Either way, it's a waste of memory.

Comment: "large lookup tables should be avoided on this platform." - or placed into flash instead of RAM.